# how to get data in batches in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, monk

I want to retrieve data from MongoDB, 5 at a time

I am using limit to **limit** the number of records returned

```
router.post('/List', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('clnName');
    collection.find({}, { limit: 5 * req.body.requestCount }, function (e, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

Here, from the client i am incrementing the **requestCount** variable so that i get data in multiples of 5. 
What i want to achieve is get first 5 data in first request, get next 5 data in second request, but what is happening is, i get first 5 data and **then first 10 data**.

What change should i make to achieve what i need?

will the use of [batch size in mongo cursor methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) solve my problem?

Comment: Use the cursor's [**`skip()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#skip) method.

Comment: u mean .skip(5*requestCount) and then a limit of 5 ?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well the clear an obvious case here is to use `.skip()` as a modifier along with `.limit()` in order to implement "paging" of data:

```js
    collection.find({}, { "limit": 5, "skip": 5 * req.body.requestCount  }, function
```

But better still if you are just processing in batches, just filter out the range you have already seen. The `_id` field makes a nice identifier for this without other sorting. So on the first request:

```js
var lastSeen = null;
    collection.find(
        {}, 
        { "limit": 5, "sort": { "_id": 1}  },
        function(err,docs) {
           docs.forEach(function(doc) {
               // do something
               lastSeen = doc._id;        // keep the _id
           });
        }
    );
```

And the next time around after storing that "lastSeen" in something like a session variable ( or other loop construct where just processing batches ):

```js
    collection.find(
        { "_id": { "$gt": lastSeen }, 
        { "limit": 5, "sort": { "_id": 1}  },
        function(err,docs) {
           docs.forEach(function(doc) {
               // do something
               lastSeen = doc._id;        // keep the _id
           });
        }
    );
```

So excluding all results less that the last `_id` value seen.

With other sorting this is still possible, but you need to take note of both the last `_id` seen and the last sorted value as well. Also keeping the `_id` seen as a list since the last value change.

```js
    var lastSeenIds = [],
        lastSeenValue = null;    

    collection.find(
        {}, 
        { "limit": 5, "sort": { "other": 1, "_id": 1 }  },
        function(err,docs) {
           docs.forEach(function(doc) {
               // do something
               if ( lastSeenValue != doc.other ) {  // clear on change
                   lastSeenValue = doc.other;
                   lastSeenIds = [];
               }
               lastSeenIds.push(doc._id);     // keep a list
           });
        }
    );
```

Then on your next iteration with variables in place:

```js
    collection.find(
        { "_id": { "$nin": lastSeenIds }, "other": { "$gte": lastSeenValue } },
        { "limit": 5, "sort": { "other": 1, "_id": 1 }  },
        function(err,docs) {
           docs.forEach(function(doc) {
               // do something
               if ( lastSeenValue != doc.other ) {  // clear on change
                   lastSeenValue = doc.other;
                   lastSeenIds = [];
               }
               lastSeenIds.push(doc._id);     // keep a list
           });
        }
    );
```

That is a lot more efficient than "skipping" through the results that match the basic query condition.

Comment: Great answer. If anyone is facing trouble with filtering on id, please make sure your id is a Mongo ObjectID instead if a string.  ex: `"_id": { "$lte": ObjectId('xxxxxxxx') }`. Reference from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052397/10524266