# Can MongoDb ObjectId be used same as auto increment integer key?

Tags: mongodb, primary-key

I am trying to understand, how the **MongoDb** primary key works, Is it same like having an `integer` field with auto increment?

Can we perform all the integer operations and condition checks on **MongoDb** generated `ObjectId`.

For example:

great than, less than, great than equal too, etc.

Comment: read this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ you will come to know how `_id` gets generated.

Comment: @sss Thanks, but I'm still confused, because the `_id` generated by MongoDb on the server is a string, right? so If I want to perform operations which can be performed on integer key, would that be possible with MongoDb primary key? I'm coming from mysql relational database, I don't know how this works, please help me understand. Thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052286/mongodb-query-where-id-threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_id` is not auto increment integer but unique, it is of type ObjectId(one of the BSON type).

You can access it as a string using for ex:

```
ObjectId("57d8f82f255ea74c7ecdd368").str
```

As primary key’s main features are:

- It must contain a unique value for each row of data.
- It cannot contain null values.

You can use `_id` as a primary key.

Comment: You mean, I can't perform operations like `sorting` and logical conditions for example give me documents where `_id < ObjectId("57d8f82f255ea74c7ecdd368")`?